# Why is my .NET app trying to load unrelated DLL files? (First chance System.BadImageFormatException in debug output)

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, dll, assemblies

While debugging, I notice the following with this C# app I have here:

It appears to try to load *all* DLL files that happen to reside in the same directory as the executable. (Even ones that are completely unrelated to anything in this project/solution.)

The app is loading and working fine, however I find the debug output weird: (paths snipped)

```
...
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'my_test.exe': Loaded '....\release\mfc42u.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'my_test.exe': Unloaded '....\release\mfc42u.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'my_test.exe': Loaded '....\release\mpiwin32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'my_test.exe': Unloaded '....\release\mpiwin32.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
...
```

The two DLLs above have absolutely nothing to do with the C# project or anything it references. Why is the executable (or the VS debugger?) trying to load these DLLs?

Comment: Why do you have those unwanted DLLs in your executable's directory in the first place?

Comment: @DOK - why the heck not!? This is pretty normal. If an app consists of more than one executable (and it's DLLs) they still normally reside in one directory.

Comment: What @DOK is saying (and I completely agree) is: if the 2 .dlls have nothing to do with your project (or anything it references), why would they be in your executable's bin directory? Did you copy them manually? If they shouldn't be loaded by anything, then they probably shouldn't be there at all...

Comment: @Pwinstein: As Martin said, if you have multiple executables in the same directory, executables that don't reference the same dlls. That's why they'd be there.

Comment: Can you configure VS to *always* break on a `System.BadImageFormatException` and post the stack trace (put a checkmark under *Debug->Exceptions->Thrown* for this exception)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this app is actively loading these DLLs after all!

This code I found in a component I was not familiar with:

```
...
foreach (FileInfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
{
...
  try
  {
    Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);
...
  catch (Exception)
  {
    // Ignore all errors caught due to the .NET framework not being able to load an assembly.
    // Not all qualifying files in the specified directories really are valid .NET assemblies.
  }
...
```

0xA3's comment about catching the 1st chance exception got me on the right track!

Comment: Wow what the hell was that developer thinking. He doesn't even just load all `*.dll` files but all files.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I snipped most of the code. It is "only" checking all `.dll` files.